# Convert ASCII Character Code to Character in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, string-formatting

I have a value I am pulling into a string that looks like this:

> M'arta

I need to have it to translate the numeric value into an actual value so that the string looks like this:

> M'arta

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in VB.NET? Here is the relevant line of code that returns this result:

```
Dim occupant as String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text
```

Comment: Sure you don't mean: M#39arta?  #69 would map to "E" or "i" depending on wether the value was intended to be hex or dec.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks. I corrected the question.

Comment: I think that this method will fail if you have "M#39arta" and "M#390arta" and you want to show "M'0arta" instead of "MƆarta" . So you have to specify the maximum length your number after"#" will have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the VB (& C#) version to what you're asking. Basically, use the [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) argument in the Regex method to allow custom parsing of the matches. In this case, we find any instances of `#<1-3_digit_number>` we want to strip the `# symbol, and convert the decimal code.

I added a second conversion in your string (`#116`) just for testing purposes. You could refactor this in to a custom method and (not sure if VB has it) lambda expression to make it universal, but I'll leave that up to you.

### VB.NET Version ([DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/LudSY))

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
        Public Shared Sub Main()
                Dim sample As [String] = "M#39ar#116a"

                Dim reg As New Regex("\x23\d{1,3}")
                Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(sample, New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ReplaceASCIICode)))
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function ReplaceASCIICode(m As Match) As [String]
                Dim code As Int32 = Int32.Parse(m.Value.Substring(1))
                Return Convert.ToString(ChrW(code))
        End Function
End Class
```

### C# Version ([DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/UGfI5))

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String sample = "M#39ar#116a";

        Regex reg = new Regex(@"\x23\d{1,3}");
        Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(sample, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceASCIICode)));
    }

    public static String ReplaceASCIICode(Match m)
    {
        Int32 code = Int32.Parse(m.Value.Substring(1));
        return Convert.ToString((char)code);
    }
}
```

---

For archival purposes, here are the versions that support `&#___;` below:

### VB.NET ([DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/omGn0))

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
        Public Shared Sub Main()
                Dim sample As [String] = "M&#39;ar&#116;a"

                Dim reg As New Regex("&#(\d{1,3});")
                Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(sample, New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ReplaceASCIICode)))
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function ReplaceASCIICode(m As Match) As [String]
                Dim code As Int32 = Int32.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value)
                Return Convert.ToString(ChrW(code))
        End Function
End Class
```

### C# ([DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/2qjVW))

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
        public static void Main()
        {
                String sample = "M&#39;ar&#116;a";

                Regex reg = new Regex(@"&#(\d{1,3});");
                Console.WriteLine(reg.Replace(sample, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceASCIICode)));
        }

        public static String ReplaceASCIICode(Match m)
        {
                Int32 code = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
                return Convert.ToString((char)code);
        }
}
```

Comment: This almost works. For some reason when I integrate this code into my application the result comes back like so: M&';arta. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, it appears that in-code it is actually giving me M&#39;arta, is there a for this regex to handle this or to strip out the & and ;?

Comment: @davemackey: I can alter the code to accept HTML "Escaping" if that's necessary? Will it follow traditional `&#<num>;` format?

Comment: @davemackey: VB.NET (http://www.ideone.com/omGn0) C# (http://www.ideone.com/2qjVW)

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the string looking for the #digits and then put the found code through  the [ChrW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) .NET function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), but here is a C# solution. I am pretty sure you can handle the conversion to Visual Basic.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        String input = "M#39arta";
        String output = Regex.Replace(input, @"#\d\d",  Replace);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static String Replace(Match match) {
        int charCode = int.Parse(match.Value.Substring(1));
        return ""+ (char)charCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh no, regex fail. It should be '#\d{1,3}'.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know regex then something like this

```
    Dim idx As Integer = occupant.IndexOf("#")
    If idx <> -1 Then
        idx += 1
        Do While idx < occupant.Length
            If IsNumeric(occupant(idx)) Then
                s &= occupant(idx)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
            idx += 1
        Loop
        If s.Length > 0 Then
            s = Convert.ToChar(CInt(s))
        End If
        Stop
    End If
```

It would need slight modification to handle multiple instances of #.